# after clicking the element implicitly wait

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, implicitwait

I want webdriver implicitly wait, after dropdown element has been clicked.
Code is below. I have commented the code line where there is code snippet but has no effect

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm") #This is a dummy website URL
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "instrumentType")) #dropdown
)
    elem.click()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) #wait implicit doesnot work
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do after clicking the dropdown? You definitely misunderstanding what implicit and explicit waits are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely misunderstanding what implicit and explicit waits are.
First of all `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)` is used for **explicit** waits.
With such `wait` you can wait for some condition like presence, visibility, clickability etc. of some element and much more conditions.
It is not a pause like `time.sleep(20)`.
`time.sleep(20)` will pause the program run for 20 seconds while  `WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "instrumentType"))` will wait **up to** 300 seconds to find presence of element located by id="instrumentType". But once it finds such element - it can be instantly - the program flow will continue to the next line instantly.
Also, as you can see, each time we use `WebDriverWait` it is for some single, specific condition.
Implicit wait (like `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`) is set for the `driver` object itself and will be kept for the entire session (until you change it, but we normally do not do it).
It defines the timeout for `driver.find_element` and `driver.find_elements` methods. Again, just a timeout. So, in case an element (or elements) found - the program flow will instantly continue. And in case element was not found till the timeout expiration - exception will be thrown.
I mean both implicit wait and explicit wait by `WebDriverWait` will throw exception, just of different type. In case of no match found.
By this:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

you creating an object named `wait` of type `WebDriverWait`. It can be used for explicit waits like above. I mean instead of

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "instrumentType"))
```

You can do as following:
Create a wait object once

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

and after that to use it as many times as you wish.
So, instead of

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "instrumentType"))
```

you will use

```py
wait.until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "instrumentType"))
```

after that you will like to click some element with

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, comments_xpath)))
```

then

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, element_path))).click()
```

while you still using the previously created `wait` object.
I hope you understand that in this expression

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

you defined the timeout for the `wait` object to be 20 seconds.

Comment: great explanation. I was searching for time.sleep() because in VBA wait() method is same for both cases. Thanks, better than documentation Selenium and many other blogs on medium I read. Thanks@Prophet

Comment: I was searching for time.sleep() in my case. But from your question arose my next question. I will be glad, if you will have time to respond. 'wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)' we use one time, and in every find_element method driver will use 20s (no more or less) to search for an element.

Comment: I added more explanations

Comment: thanks Prophet, due to your thorough explanation, I got interested and looked also for 'expected condition' class (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). It is easy now, to know in which circumstance to to use explicit wait while element loads, then click, and where for debugging purpose i can use time.sleep(). Thanks a lot, for your detailed explanations, it boosted to get more though your explanations are detailed and precise.

Comment: I'm really happy it helped. You are always welcome